# ASP.NET Core 3 - Is it possible to add a SignalR service in Configure method when dependencies required for a factory method are available?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am learning ASP.NET core and struggling trying to inject some ILogger instances required as parameters within a factory method used within my `AddJsonProtocol` of the `AddSignalR` method. See code below.

The `JsonConvertersFactory` factory method creates the JsonConverters for serialization/deserialization in signalR. It is used within the `.AddJsonProtocol` anonymous method when adding SignalR service.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();

    services.AddHostedService<MqttKafkaBridge>();
    services.AddHostedService<ConsumerService>();
    services.AddLogging();

    // how can I retrieve ILogger<MotionDetection>, ILogger<MotionInfo>, ILogger<JsonVisitor>?
    services.AddSignalR(o => o.EnableDetailedErrors = true)
      .AddJsonProtocol(options =>
        {
          options.PayloadSerializerOptions = JsonConvertersFactory.CreateDefaultJsonConverters(LoggerMotionDetection, LoggerMotionInfo, LoggerJsonVisitor);
        });

    services.AddCustomConfiguration(services);
}
```

I could build a temporary service provider and add logger dependencies so that the SignalR Json protocol could be configued. However I am not sure if this is considered an anti-pattern....

```
var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var loggerMD = sp.GetService<ILogger<MotionDetection>>();
var loggerMI = sp.GetService<ILogger<MotionInfo>>();
var loggerJV = sp.GetService<ILogger<JsonVisitor>>();
```

When I use `BuildServiceProvider` I receive the following warning message:

```
Startup.cs(53,22): warning ASP0000: Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an additional copy of singleton services being created. Consider alternatives such as dependency injecting services as parameters to 'Configure'.
```

Is it possible to add a service in `Configure` method, i.e. add the SignalR service in Configure when ILogger instances can be resolved?

OR

Is it possible to inject the SignalRService in Configure method and update it's Json protocol configuration?

**Update**

Tried injecting ISignalRServerBuilder in `Configure`but receive an exception that could not find an ISignalRServerBuilder instance in container registry (Autofac).

Any ideas?

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ISignalRServerBuilder builder, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            // this tries to build the options from the service container but 
            // the builder is null
            builder.AddJsonProtocol(op =>
            {
                var lMD = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ILogger<MotionDetectionConverter>>();
                var lMI = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ILogger<MotionInfoConverter>>();
                var lJV = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<ILogger<JsonVisitor>>();

                op.PayloadSerializerOptions = JsonConvertersFactory.CreateDefaultJsonConverters(lMD, lMI, lJV);
            });

            ...
        }
```

Comment: You don't need to create the loggers. If your SignalR hubs or controllers have a dependency on `ILogger<Whatever>` the DI container will create this instance when creating the controller or hub

Comment: Thanks for responding, appreciated :) I need to create the ```ILogger<Whatever>``` for use in the ```.AddJsonProtocol``` anonymous method where they are a dependency of my factory method to create the custom JsonConverters